# What happened to the Shadow son of Stannis after killing Renly?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Melisandre promises Stannis to give a son in Season 2 on *Game of Thrones*. She births a Shadow/Ghost in front of Davos. He killed Renly Barathoeon. What happened to that shadow, is he back with Stannis or Melisandre? Or he is free to roam anywhere in world? Or did he simply disappear after the task.

What happened to this character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Game of Thrones Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow) Weaknesses section:

> Shadows live very short lives, created only for the tasks they were given. Although they can become invisible, a mirror will compromise the creature's location. It is implied by Catelyn that Shadows inherit the physical features of the men who fathered them, as the Shadow that killed Renly Baratheon bore a striking resemblance to its "father," Stannis.

It's clearly mentioned that Shadows live very short lives and are created mainly for the task, so this Shadow might be no more.

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because the GoT Wikia isn't a reliable source: being fan-edited, it could potentially contain all sorts of uncited nonsense.

Comment: @Randal'Thor so what you do consider as a reliable source?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The show itself; behind-the-scenes material such as interviews with the creators; the books on which the show is based; ... even just a bit of common-sense reasoning is preferable to a quote from an unreliable source.